How to modify Tableau formula to set specific date and activity to 0?
I’m working on a Tableau Desktop formula and need help adjusting it.
I need to modify it so that the entry with Date: 7/23/2024, activity_category: TimeOff, activity_name: LOA UTO, and activity_duration: 30 is set to 0.
My Date column could have one single date or many of the same date listing down on rows for each employee, example:
Employee        Date        activity_category   activity_name   activity_duration   Credits Used MAX
Gracie        7/15/2024             TimeOff           LOA UTO             30                       1
Gracie        7/16/2024             TimeOff           LOA UTO             30                       1
Gracie        7/23/2024               Break           Break               15                       0
Gracie        7/23/2024               Meal            Meal                30                       0 
Gracie        7/23/2024              TimeOff          LOA UTO             30                       1
Gracie        7/23/2024              On Queue         On Queue            120                      0

Here’s a sample of my data for reference:
Employee             Date       activity_category   activity_name   activity_duration   Credits Used MAX
Gracie             7/23/2024      TimeOff             LOA UTO              30                   1

I created a Tableau desktop formula, and I would like to have the last column titled Credits Used MAX turn from 1 to 0 only if the employee has activities with the same Date.  If there is only one individual Date for the employee this means he/she were out the entire day and should receive a 1, which in this example it is correct.
IF [activity_category] = 'OnQueueWork' AND  [activity_name (Custom SQL Query2)] IN ('OnQueueWork', 'On Queue') AND  INT([activity_duration]) >= 120 THEN 0 ELSEIF [activity_category] = 'TimeOff' AND  INT([activity_duration]) >= 120 THEN 1 ELSEIF { FIXED [Date] : COUNTD([Date]) } = 1 THEN IF [activity_category] = 'TimeOff' AND  [activity_name (Custom SQL Query2)] = 'LOA UTO' AND  INT([activity_duration]) = 30 THEN 1 ELSEIF [activity_category] = 'OnQueueWork' AND  [activity_name (Custom SQL Query2)] = 'Overtime' AND  INT([activity_duration]) = 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSEIF { FIXED [Date], [activity_category], [activity_name (Custom SQL Query2)], [activity_duration] :    COUNT([Date]) } > 1 THEN IF [activity_category] = 'TimeOff' AND  [activity_name (Custom SQL Query2)] = 'LOA UTO' AND  INT([activity_duration]) <= 30 THEN 0 ELSE 0 END ELSE 0 END 
